# Why does my program work even when I enter nothing at the prompt?

Tags: perl

I have the following script that prompts for a user name and password and checks if they match. However, it prints `Success!` even if I just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the prompts, without actually entering a user name or password. Why?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

%data = qw(
    javad   root
    ali     1234
    george  password
);

print "Please enter your name :\n";
$name = <STDIN>;
chomp($name);
$pass = $data{$name};

#receiving password from user
#compare it with correct password
#print the result
print "What is your password ?\n";
$guess = <STDIN>;
chomp($guess);

$whileTest = "True";
while ($whileTest eq "True") {
    if ($pass eq $guess) {
        print "Success!\n";
        $whileTest = "False";
    }
    elsif ($pass ne $guess) {
        print "Wrong password , Try again :\n";
        $guess = <STDIN>;
        chomp($guess);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you don't actually require that `$name` exist in `%data`.  Therefore `$data{$name}` returns [undef](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html), which will `eq` a blank password.

Comment: Please user proper indenting in your code. I've cleaned it up for you to make it more readable.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: What squiguy is saying is that you should always have `use strict; use warnings;` in your scripts and modules. After the `#!` line.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix

```
$pass = $data{$name} or die "No password for $name";
```

When you enter blank name, password is `undef` which later compared with empty string equals to true and gives access. `use warnings;` would at least complain about such comparison.

Comment: what do you have against "0" as a password? :)

Comment: @ysth I have nothing efficient against it. Actually I have, `or` is more efficient than `//` to prevent it. :)

Comment: `defined( $pass = $data{$name} ) or die "No password for $name";` or `$pass = $data{$name}; die "No password for $name" if !defined($pass);`